# What is the best way to measure the time a user does something in Java?

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I am making an Android app in Java and want the variable timeHeldDown to be set to the time the user is holding down a button on our app.  Past a certain length of time, a help menu should pop up for the user.

I have looked around a found both the Timer and TimerTask classes within Java.util.  Are one of these better than the others to use, or is there another class entirely that would be better?

System.currentTimeMillis(); would probably work.

Comment: "better" will get into "opinion based" territory, which SO doesn't do.  But if you can reword this to "what are the differences", or possibly the advantages of each, then this may be answerable.

Comment: As this is only about measuring simple actions, currentTimeInMillis() seems accurate. In other words: avoid rocket science; go for simplest thing that works for you.

Comment: Look carefully to javadocs - Timer and TimerTask are not alternatives. They are two components of task scheduling. And no, this is not what you need in your case. You can for example extend android.widget.Button overriding onKeyDown/onKeyUp methods and calculate a time diff of these callbacks

Answer (score 2):

Timer and TimerTask are not libraries for timing, they are in fact for task scheduling and running certain tasks in the background etc..

One way would be to use the current system time, although not a good way to do this, it is the most simplest, I would declare global variables for timeEnd/Start and a final time something like the following:

```
public double timeHeldDown;
public long timeStart;
public long timeEnd;

//OnPress
timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis()

//OnDepress
timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
timeHeldDown = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is the StopWatch class from commons-lang.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/index.html

```
StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
stopWatch.start();

// do stuff

stopWatch.stop();

long nanos = stopWatch.getNanos(); // time in nanoseconds
long millis = stopWatch.getTime(); // time in millis
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer given by Conner Turner, in the same code you can use System.nanoTime() for more precision.